# Proving a set of inequalities implies another inequality

Tags: inequality

I have a system of inequalities (for $\gamma, S, \psi$ real numbers):
\begin{align}
\gamma &> 1
\\
\psi &\in (0,1)
\\
S &\geq 3
\\
\\
\ln \left[ \frac{1}{S} \gamma^{1/S} \right] - \frac{\psi}{S} 
&> - \ln \left[S-1 + \frac{1}{\gamma} \right]
\\
\ln \left[ \frac{1}{S} \gamma^{1/S} \right] - \psi 
&> - \ln \left[S-1 + \frac{1}{\gamma} \right]
\\
\gamma(1-\sqrt{\psi}) &< 1
\end{align}
And I want to show the following:
$$
1 + \ln \left[ \gamma \left( 1 - \sqrt{\psi} \right) \right] - \gamma \left( 1 - \sqrt\psi \right) \geq -\psi
$$

Any suggestions for how to even approach showing this (or a full-blown proof!) would be greatly appreciated.

- My inclination was to rely on inequalities for logs (e.g. $\ln (1+x) \ge x/(1+x)$), but this has gotten me no where.
- I have "verified" the result numerically.
- I have tried Mathematica (and Matlab less carefully), and it seemed to not be able to simplify.

Thank you!

Comment: From $\gamma > \frac{1}{S-1} \left[ \frac{S-1+\sqrt{\psi}}{1-\sqrt{\psi}}\right]$, we have $\gamma(1-\sqrt{\psi}) > 1 + \frac{\sqrt{\psi}}{S-1} > 1$ which is inconsistent with $\gamma(1-\sqrt{\psi}) < 1$. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Thank you @Anand! There was a typo -- the last equation should not have been included!(!) This is now fixed.

Comment: The inequality $\ln \left[ \frac{1}{S} \gamma^{1/S} \right] - \frac{\psi}{S} 
> - \ln \left[S-1 + \frac{1}{\gamma} \right]$ is strictly weaker than  $\ln \left[ \frac{1}{S} \gamma^{1/S} \right] - \psi 
> - \ln \left[S-1 + \frac{1}{\gamma} \right]$. Can the first one be ignored?

Comment: Yes, thanks -- I left the first in because it has intuitive meaning in the underlying problem, but I can remove it if that helps with clarity.